# Javabean error trapping/handling

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans

I am just learning Java and have a question on calls from an XPage to a JavaBean.

I am working on a JavaBean I got from [Declan Sciolla-Lynch's blog](http://www.qtzar.com/getting-to-the-java-roots-of-xpages-part-11/) that works perfectly in most situations. The link points to the example code.

Essentially the JavaBean connects into the names.nsf and pulls various fields for lookup.  IE User's phone or email address. Similar to an existing LotusScript class we had implemented in the past.   We have a secondary Directory with additional information that I took Declan's example and modified it. It now points to a different server, nsf and has additional fields. It works under normal conditions.

However I have run into to two issues that cause the class to fail and to show an unhelpful "Can't Instantiate Class" error.  The issues were with the ACL and database replication formula and will be resolved but I'd like to try to minimize environmentally caused issues.  The problem is I can't trap this in EL or SSJS because it is happening at a JavaBean/class level.  There is a try{} catch {} around the Java code but the "Can't Instantiate Class" error still occurs.  I am attempting to load the default values of three fields on an XPage with SSJS calls to the JavaBean.

Is there a way to capture the error in the JavaBean and pass it to the XPages so that I can test for a loaded class before calling the managed bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can't Instantiate Class" error occurs when your Java class constructor throws an error.

Add a try/catch block to your Java bean constructor and deliver the error message to your XPage in catch block:

first add an error messages control "messages1" to your XPage

```
<xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
```

and then write your error message in Java bean to this control

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    public MyClass() {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( "messages1", 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), ""));
        }
```

Comment: What if there's no display errors control on the page?  Where would the message go?  Still out to the console?  available to Xpages Log Reader? I assume it would just disappear in that event.... Not sure I like that.  I'd like to some how send the error to a nice errorPage I think...

Comment: How about setting a private variable if an error is thrown and then having a getter like isInitError and maybe another one for getErrorMsg? Then you could test for isInitError before using the bean methods?

Comment: @David, you're right. Usually I have a custom error page and show serious errors there. This is more an answer to question's last paragraph.

Comment: Great Point.  The Custom Error page solution would make a great blog post or dare I say...  a video.  :)

Comment: @Knut:  Thank you. That just about did it.  I had to change the catch from NotesException to Exception you had in your example to get the  catch to fire otherwise it kept showing the class error.  I then got the page to render but the xp:messages area shows up (yellow) but doesn't show any error message.

Comment: Seems `e.getMessage()` returns nothing in your case. You might add a string like `"Couldn't load the default values... " + e.getMessage()` so you'd get at least a visible error message. If you don't know what's the real error cause then add an additional line `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch block and look at server console for stack trace.